# Amazon lex - Can the bot initiate a message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I am new to amazon lex. I wanted to have the bot initiate a conversation instead of the user triggering the start flow by asking a question, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, it has to be handled client-side, i.e, you won't have this behavior in the test interface.

In Facebook Messenger, for example, you can setup a [Greeting Text](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/greeting-text).

Comment: Facebook link is broken